# After sending byte arrays via dataoutputstream, the received byte arrays are not equal to original byte arrays

Tags: java, sockets, arrays, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

For some reasons, I need to send multiple byte arrays separately via server socket, and client socket will receive these byte arrays. After sending byte arrays, I found byte arrays received in client socket are not equal to those in server socket. If I use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream, then everything works fine, but for my need, I can't use ObjectOutputStream & ObjectInputStream, because my server need to connect more than 2 sockets.

Here is Server and Client code:

Server(Sender):

```
    private void sendData() throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

        File file = new File(filePath);
        byte[] fileByte = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        // Convert file into byte array
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(fileByte);

        while (!decoder.isDecoded()) {
            byte[] packet = new byte[encoder.getPacketLength()];
            encoder.getPacket(packet, 0);

            if (Math.random() < 0.1)
                continue;

            // Send data HERE!!!
            outputStream.writeInt(encoder.getPacketLength());
            outputStream.write(packet);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte value : packet) {
                sb.append(value);
            }
            serverLog("Packet content= " + sb.toString());

            decoder.addPacket(packet, 0);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
```

Client(Receiver):

```
public void receiveData() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    int len = dis.readInt();

    while (!decoder.isDecoded()) {
        byte[] packet = new byte[len];

        dis.read(packet, 0, len);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte value : packet) {
            sb.append(value);
        }
        messageArea.append("Packet content= " + sb.toString() + "\n");

        decoder.addPacket(packet, 0);
    }
}
```

---

log from server:

```
Packet content= 8312654-7646-55-71-522462106-89115-98-107-66-9445-61-78-99-43-52528422-10765-3719-1243-114-115-5869-119-92-113591131276057-905042126-7557940-2850118-9737-6512759-93-393-89-96104-789-7694747-118-61-79-97-872-4369-82-11923-805-62-9527-38-1195-13107673425588-92-49-44-97-7811812416-781244-100
Packet content= -10295-4-73-809789-87-97-9095-55-11-7440100-2871-89-68-59-3739-2073-1286290-21-106-2-25-1263646-107-84-9-42-4491-418419-469395-61-52-32-85-38-107-8385-6559-1286575-56-1029-5991-7551-10390-25-94-5072-2318-62-12360-818-11719-73710076121-584012212645-20-170-45089-87401082110113-7-1034873-877
Packet content= -37-732-59-1071015223-34-2745-4322265-18-108-97126-22-56083-131-61-16069536-10-7092-36-50-96-72-3133-79-11751-3671-91-48-14-54-113-8295-124-18-78125-117-12811911042-34108-94-33-92-113268272-41-23992553-69-72997619-1166735417-76-126-58121-7595-443265-944-44-124104-201040-803310126-125-8449-8
Packet content= -102110606194-6037-2-63-6025-112-17-36-3629-93112-86-116-54-14118-124121315341-11923-119-12246-1-973-31-22-9-111-12614-37-1456-10456-9450-11823811378-779-111101-31-101-843217-124-16107-108107101-7743-108-100-5475113119-6647-7185-96-683-12710756-9896111-1072318-3982-6288-7496-5514-18373957-71108-3232
Packet content= -6689-124263-68321112-19-6730-68-12223-125105-51444110862-11063-114-41-76-5275-7-15105-865826-5049-12386124123-121-10460-863108-65-481142910461-97-11912453-10718-6711787-91-37-97910-22-1963-88-116114-138375-2082027-128126-8529-3632242-772-105106-35-41-44-573126-7512038-62-733838-434433-9-59
Packet content= -9652035246-1482-59-63699991-47-25-2-15127-55-42-97-106-11966-15-4344462-68-2-916794121-31-11164-40-73-8104342-69-38-122986-11584-57-106-35-49-120-15138-19121-32-88-62-5127-95114-26-34-75-377155-6911914-4210849-116-7028-8180-817585-108-76-3337-21-4589108-121794-85109-6810644-102101106-68-5-127
Packet content= -127-124-61-24479910112178-45-47-952540-122-70100-120-17-5114-127-69-12-38-100-111-21-111-44113-10-12490-72884-9549-1115580-7653-16100-7889-22103-747-476698-9-68-83-301112667-1712127-64-45-746-1054497-7071108-109-9-8946-4259-121-106-121-27-6761-3447-1177476-7271-95-75-107-42-331886-119-10578-6098-128-2287-52
Packet content= 5244-100-68-1215109-27-6810-774491-11-29102-6267-621964-975427701107495-33578037-1924-5611657210-46-16-94-53-92-5282-11353-10359-38-1-385212480-12710119-597634-108-67-49109101-69-7933-10189120-76104-46106-64223-44-10-4789-1213910192-125-60-5-20-37-901-5-104103-739314-4414-1123759-31-45-72
Packet content= 119-4161558-7832-8310329-118-91122-85-37-33-30-52-101087-123784011115-57-31-1166-31-55-43-13-49-5812464-16-1382-30-3810445117659-70810584-46113-11-5111-1251-428299112-816596-1091021353-4679-3526-10363100-10-4-318-49-117-10449103105-11190-94-5310633-2-123-5268-119124-12297-106-114-102110-35-12094-128
Packet content= -381-70-109-26112-2552-92-40-39-22966-36-69-118-116-19-4848-9-12869-102-4558-2198362-121-553776-84-118-93125-12374128555-8688-2-729-43126-3-10083-26-64119-6010577-12263-4-74-44-11028-216447727-5082-104100-3410673529-8970-27110-81-90-1221185-22-249510515-123-157817-43-11961-93141-8512-77-7352
```

log from client:

```
Packet content= 8312654-7646-55-71-522462106-89115-98-107-66-9445-61-78-99-43-52528422-10765-3719-1243-114-115-5869-119-92-113591131276057-905042126-7557940-2850118-9737-6512759-93-393-89-96104-789-7694747-118-61-79-97-872-4369-82-11923-805-62-9527-38-1195-13107673425588-92-49-44-97-7811812416-781244-100
Packet content= 000110-10295-4-73-809789-87-97-9095-55-11-7440100-2871-89-68-59-3739-2073-1286290-21-106-2-25-1263646-107-84-9-42-4491-418419-469395-61-52-32-85-38-107-8385-6559-1286575-56-1029-5991-7551-10390-25-94-5072-2318-62-12360-818-11719-73710076121-584012212645-20-170-45089-87401082110113-7-103
Packet content= 4873-877000110-37-732-59-1071015223-34-2745-4322265-18-108-97126-22-56083-131-61-16069536-10-7092-36-50-96-72-3133-79-11751-3671-91-48-14-54-113-8295-124-18-78125-117-12811911042-34108-94-33-92-113268272-41-23992553-69-72997619-1166735417-76-126-58121-7595-443265-944-44-124104-201040
Packet content= -803310126-125-8449-8000110-102110606194-6037-2-63-6025-112-17-36-3629-93112-86-116-54-14118-124121315341-11923-119-12246-1-973-31-22-9-111-12614-37-1456-10456-9450-11823811378-779-111101-31-101-843217-124-16107-108107101-7743-108-100-5475113119-6647-7185-96-683-12710756-9896111-1072318-3982-6288
Packet content= -7496-5514-18373957-71108-3232000110-6689-124263-68321112-19-6730-68-12223-125105-51444110862-11063-114-41-76-5275-7-15105-865826-5049-12386124123-121-10460-863108-65-481142910461-97-11912453-10718-6711787-91-37-97910-22-1963-88-116114-138375-2082027-128126-8529-3632242-772-105106-35-41
Packet content= -44-573126-7512038-62-733838-434433-9-59000110-9652035246-1482-59-63699991-47-25-2-15127-55-42-97-106-11966-15-4344462-68-2-916794121-31-11164-40-73-8104342-69-38-122986-11584-57-106-35-49-120-15138-19121-32-88-62-5127-95114-26-34-75-377155-6911914-4210849-116-7028-8180-817585-108-76
Packet content= -3337-21-4589108-121794-85109-6810644-102101106-68-5-127000110-127-124-61-24479910112178-45-47-952540-122-70100-120-17-5114-127-69-12-38-100-111-21-111-44113-10-12490-72884-9549-1115580-7653-16100-7889-22103-747-476698-9-68-83-301112667-1712127-64-45-746-1054497-7071108-109-9-8946-4259-121-106-121-27-67
Packet content= 61-3447-1177476-7271-95-75-107-42-331886-119-10578-6098-128-2287-520001105244-100-68-1215109-27-6810-774491-11-29102-6267-621964-975427701107495-33578037-1924-5611657210-46-16-94-53-92-5282-11353-10359-38-1-385212480-12710119-597634-108-67-49109101-69-7933-10189120-76104-46106-64223-44
Packet content= -10-4789-1213910192-125-60-5-20-37-901-5-104103-739314-4414-1123759-31-45-72000110119-4161558-7832-8310329-118-91122-85-37-33-30-52-101087-123784011115-57-31-1166-31-55-43-13-49-5812464-16-1382-30-3810445117659-70810584-46113-11-5111-1251-428299112-816596-1091021353-4679-3526-10363100
Packet content= -10-4-318-49-117-10449103105-11190-94-5310633-2-123-5268-119124-12297-106-114-102110-35-12094-128000110-381-70-109-26112-2552-92-40-39-22966-36-69-118-116-19-4848-9-12869-102-4558-2198362-121-553776-84-118-93125-12374128555-8688-2-729-43126-3-10083-26-64119-6010577-12263-4-74-44-11028-216447727-5082
```

Everyone can see there are always 6 integers "000110" inserted into the received packets after the first packet, how do I edit these code to prevent this problem and ensure the sent packets and received packets are equal? Please help me, I would appreciate your kind help. :)

Comment: You appear to be assuming that all the data will be read in a single call to `read()`. That's generally not a safe assumption for a stream. (It's *possible* that it is for `DataInputStream`, but I suspect it's not.) You should *always* use the return value of `read` to find out how much data has actually been read, and loop round until you've read everything you expect.

Comment: From the server side you send the packt's length for every packet, while in the client side you read the length only once. Shouldn't you read the length for every packet? Also consider the previous comment about reading the whole packet.

Comment: Typically you `flush()` the data output stream after a write to make sure that everything is transmitted.

Comment: if (Math.random() < 0.1) continue; What is this for? I guess it does not matter, but this won´t work for files > 2GB.

Comment: I move `int len = dis.readInt();` into while loop, and change `dis.read(packet, 0, len);` into `dis.readFully(packet, 0, len);`, it can be work well now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that `read()` filled the buffer, without checking the return value. It isn't specified to do that, only to transfer at least one byte. Use `readFully()` to get that behaviour.